# Git repository not pushing the folder created within the SpringBoot project by create-react-app to Git

Tags: reactjs, git, spring-boot, gitlab, npx

I have created a SpringBoot API which is interacted with by the frontend React project to generate a frontend website.

To create the react project I used the npx create-react-app command within the terminal of IDEA in the project root folder of the SpringBoot project.

I have been able to push the git lab repository from the root directory of the SpringBoot project successfully and all java files are successfully pushed to the remote Git repository, unfortunately though, the 'frontend' directory which contains the React project is not being pushed to the GitLab repo successfully.

Only an empty directory called 'frontend' is displayed on the GitLab web GUI, with a small red GitLab icon displayed next to it, I think this indicates it contains nothing or was not pushed correctly. It also cannot be clicked and has the commit id next to it: @f4bh345c

There is no Git repository inside the 'frontend' directory.

I have only pushed to one branch of the remote repository, not the master branch but the main branch.

I do not understand why the 'frontend' directory is not pushed with the rest of the directories and files within the springboot project.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It sounds strongly like a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: @SwissCodeMen How would I use it as a submodule? Currently it is the 'frontend' directory, that page uses an example of an external library being a subnmodule, I don't understand how I can label the frontend directory as a submodule. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to remove the .git folder in your react app by running the command "rm -fr .git" within the react app folder.
2. Do the same with the main folder which has both projects. check if the .git folder has been successfully removed by running the "git status" command in both folders. If you get "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git", you are good to go now.
3. Delete and create a new remote repository.
4. In your main folder which has both projects, do "git init" to initialize a new git repo
5. Then git add .
6. Then git commit -m "Initial commit"
7. You can now successfully add the remote repo by following the instructions given when you created it in step 3 and push your changes.

N:B Don't forget to include the .gitignore in your parent folder which has both projects.. You can copy it from your react app project.